# How to bypass Instagram parsing protection?

Tags: python, parsing, request, python-requests, instagram

I wrote a parser for Instagram posts, everything works fine on the local machine.

Code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()

headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36'
}
session.headers.update(headers)

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BwxCPidhe0V/'

response = session.get(url)

if response.history:
    print("Request was redirected")
    for resp in response.history:
        print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
    print("Final destination:")
    print(response.status_code, response.url)
else:
    print("Request was not redirected")
```

When executing this code, my request is not redirected to the authorization page https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/p/BwxCPidhe0V/

But when I upload the code for any hosting (Heroku, repl.it, pythonanywhere), my request is redirected to the authorization page.

How can a bypass of this system be implemented so that when requested through hosting it is not redirected to the authorization page?

Preferably using python standard requests library rather than using solonium

Sandbox:
https://repl.it/@briler/bypass-Instagram-parsing-protection#main.py

Comment: try ``selenium``

Comment: This question neglects instagram's policies.